# how to specify optional anonymous ienumerable parameters in c# abstract method

Tags: c#

**I have the following base class**

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

**And a class the inherits it.**

```
public class CustomerRepository: BaseRepository<Customer>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Customer>GetAll()
    {
        return null;
    }
}


public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**what i want to do is using this class**

```
public class Sales
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public decimal Total {get;set;}
}
```

**this doesn't work**

```
public class SalesRepository: BaseRepository<Sales>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Sales>GetAll(IEnumerable<Customer> Customers)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**My question is, how to I modify my BaseClass to have optional ienumerable parameters of that i can then use as needed.**

Comment: You can't. through Overriding you're not allowed to change the signature of the method. you can try `new` modifier in your method

Comment: Can you put an example, I am afraid I'm a little green

Comment: the new modifier hides a method instead of overriding, but it wont help you in this case. you are forced to implement the GetAll() method as declared in your abstract class with the exact same signature. what would be interesting is, where do you use the GetAll() method and why do you chose a abstract method? maybe you can use delegates instead.

Comment: @RedSoxFred I have posted an answer pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this change

```
public class SalesRepository : BaseRepository<Sales>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Sales> GetAll()
    {
        return GetAll(null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Sales> GetAll(IEnumerable<Customer> Customers)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

BaseRepository<Sales> rep = new SalesRepository();
rep.GetAll();
```

this will call overridden version and makes a call to GetAll(null).
To pass value to GetAll() method you need to have do the following

```
SalesRepository srep = new SalesRepository();
srep.GetAll(new Customer[] { new Customer() });
```

Answer (score 4):

The `GetAll(IEnumerable<Customer> Customers)` function amounts to a new method.  It does not have the same signature of the base, and so cannot be overridden in this way.  The `SalesRepository` class, if it is to be a `BaseRepository<Sales>`, must implement the `GetAll()` method as is.

Comment: If a `CustomerRepository` supports an additional operation, viz: `GetAll(IEnumerable<Customer> Customers)` (which, incidentally, I would consider renaming), it can be declared and implemented there, not in the base class.  However, you are still stuck with having to implement the base `GetAll()` method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can either [mark parameter as optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) or you can make overloads to the method in your base class, both of which will result in the same thing.  When you mark a parameter as optional the compiler simply makes the overloads for you.

Ultimately you probably need to make two methods in your base class and then either hide one (make private) in your implementation of each parent class or have it throw an error.  If you can figure out a good way to have default values then that may work as well.